# What does the O in Big-O Notation mean?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I‘m trying to wrap my head around the meaning of the Landau-Notation in the context of analysing an algorithm‘s complexity.

What exactly does the **O** formally mean in Big-O-Notation?

So the way I understand it is that **O(g(x))** gives a **set** of functions which grow as rapidly or slower as g(x), meaning, for example in the case of O(n^2):

[image: Example with O^2]
where t(x) could be, for instance, x + 3 or x^2 + 5. Is my understanding correct?

Furthermore, are the following notations correct?

[image]

I saw the following written down by a tutor. What does this mean? How can you use less or equal, if the O-Notation returns a set?

[image]

Could I also write something like this?

[image]

Comment: The smaller equals seems more like an explanation of usage than correct math. For a big enough n, an exponential is larger than a quadratic and a quadratic is larger than a linear

Comment: What does that title mean?

Comment: Where did you find the first example with O(n²) ? It is *completely wrong*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the way I understand it is that O(g(x)) gives a set of functions which grow as rapidly or slower as g(x).

This explanation of Big-Oh notation is correct.

> f(n) = n^2 + 5n - 2,  f(n) is an element of O(n^2)

Yes, we can say that. `O(n^2)` in plain English, represents "set of all functions that grow as rapidly as or slower than n^2". So, `f(n)` satisfies that requirement.

> O(n) is a subset of O(n^2), O(n^2) is a subset of O(2^n)

This notation is correct and it comes from the definition. Any function that is in `O(n)`, is also in `O(n^2)` since growth rate of it is slower than `n^2`. `2^n` is an exponential time complexity, whereas `n^2` is polynomial. You can take limit of `n^2` / `2^n` as `n` goes to infinity and prove that `O(n^2)` is a subset of `O(2^n)` since `2^n` grows bigger.

> O(n) <= O(n^2) <= O(2^n)

This notation is tricky. As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1437976), we don't have "less than or equal to" for sets. I think tutor meant that time complexity for the functions belonging to the set `O(n)` is less than (or equal to) the time complexity for the functions belonging to the set `O(n^2)`. Anyways, this notation doesn't really seem familiar, and it's best to avoid such ambiguities in textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

> `O(g(x))` gives a set of functions which grow as rapidly or slower as `g(x)`

That's technically right, but a bit imprecise. A better description contains the addenda

> `O(g(x))` gives the set of functions which are *asymptotically* bounded above by `g(x)`, *up to constant factors*.

This may seem like a nitpick, but one inference from the imprecise definition is wrong.

The 'fixed version' of your first equation, if you make the variables match up and have one limit sign, seems to be:

[image: first]

This is **incorrect**: the ratio only has to be less than or equal to some fixed constant `c > 0`.

Here is the correct version:

[image: second]

where `c` is some fixed positive real number, that does not depend on `n`.

For example, `f(x) = 3 (n^2)` is in `O(n^2)`: one constant `c` that works for this `f` is `c = 4`. Note that the requirement isn't 'for all `c > 0`', but rather 'for at least one constant `c > 0`'

The rest of your remarks are accurate. The `<=` signs in that expression are an unusual usage, but it's true if `<=` means set inclusion. I wouldn't worry about that expression's meaning.

---

There's other, more subtle reasons to talk about 'boundedness' rather than growth rates. For instance, consider the `cosine` function. `|cos(x)|` is in `O(1)`, but its derivative fluctuates from negative one to positive one even as `x` increases to infinity.

If you take 'growth rate' to mean something like the derivative, example like these become tricky to talk about, but saying `|cos(x)|` is bounded by `2` is clear.

For an even better example, consider the [logistic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). The logistic function is `O(1)`, however, its derivative and growth rate (on positive numbers) is positive. It is strictly increasing/always growing, while `1` has a growth rate of `0`. This seems to conflict with the first definition without lots of additional clarifying remarks of what 'grow' means.

An always growing function in `O(1)` (image from the Wikipedia link):
[image: Logistic]

Comment: Growth rate refers to the percentage change of a specific variable within a specific time period. Therefore I believe, you do not need to add the "up to constant factors" part.

Comment: cn² or n² makes no difference, this is plain wrong. The limit on the right does not exist. And even if you interpret it as being infinity, the inequality just expresses that t(x) does not exceed infinity !?!

Comment: @Muhteva That's correct. Using 'growth rate' probably causes too much confusion with 'running time', so I've reworded the definition.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My bad, I automatically misread that as having one limit sign for the whole expression, but it's still nonsensical. I'll remove that.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: not even. c.g(x)-f(x) does not need to have a limit for the big-O to exist. Being bounded is enough.

Comment: @Muhteva I've added some more explanation and an example for why 'growth rate' might not be a good way to define big-O-notation; let me know what you think.

Comment: I see your point, and I agree that "boundedness" is much more correct way to interpret Big-Oh notation. But the problem with negative derivative is that, can we find such functions in algorithms? I mean, can we implement a function that will execute less number of operations when we increase the n, input size? I think growth rate starts making sense when we exclude such functions. I really wonder if we can come up with such algorithms. Sigmoid function or cosine cannot be time complexity of any algorithm, I guess.

Comment: @Muhteva Since time complexity has to be an integer, there’s no cosine or ‘always increasing but bounded’ time complexities, but you can get behavior that’s as close to that as you want. For a ‘real’ algorithm with highly fluctuating runtime, my first thought is a function f(n) that prints the indices of all set bits in n’s binary representation.